# How to assign a variable value to a variable from another file?

Tags: shell, variables, ksh

I have a sql file **abc.sql** having a SELECT SQL statement

```
SELECT COL FROM $D_SCHEMA.TABLE;
```

I have a shell script **script.ksh**

```
D_SCHEMA=DEV
EXEC_SQL=`cat abc.sql`
#echo $EXEC_SQL

#Function db_sql, which exports data to a csv file
db_sql "EXPORT TO /app/dev FILE ${EXEC_SQL}"
```

Now I am not able to assign the value to ***$D_SCHEMA*** from the sql file when the content is assigned to a variable in shell script.

Currently the variable is treated as a literal in the shell script.

```
echo $EXEC_SQL
SELECT COL FROM $D_SCHEMA.TABLE
```

Expected output

```
echo $EXEC_SQL
SELECT COL FROM DEV.TABLE
```

How do I go about solving this?

Comment: You want a substitution within a substitution that won't happen. Why aren't you assigning EXEC_SQL with your select statement instead of using that `cat abc.sql` thing ?

Comment: The select statement are in the .sql file & we have to read the content from that file. How else can we get the select statement to be assigned to EXEC_SQL?

Comment: EXEC_SQL="SELECT COL FROM $D_SCHEMA.TABLE;" for one. Or have this in the sql file and source the file instead. You see, I might be wrong but, I feel like this is a XY problem, can you state the whole problem and what you've tried so far ?

Comment: `D_SCHEMA` can be expanded, does an example like this help?  `eval new_var=\""$EXEC_SQL"\"; echo "$new_var"`

Comment: First of all the sql file is provided by some application, we have to make use of that file for the export. So we can't have the expression EXEC_SQL="SELECT COL FROM $D_SCHEMA.TABLE;" in sql file. We somehow have to get the select statement from that file & replace the schema name & few other variables & then feed to the function db_sql.

Comment: @Milag You are bang on with this! This worked like a charm :)
Could you let me know how this actually works? I mean how does the interpretation takes place?

Comment: Example posted.  After initial var expansion, shell builtin `eval` can operate like a second round of var expansion; outer \ and quotes avoids some unwanted interpreting.  shell manual explains it better.

Comment: @Milag Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/ksh

# one example using eval

D_SCHEMA=DEV
EXEC_SQL='SELECT COL FROM $D_SCHEMA.TABLE'

echo "$EXEC_SQL"
# output: SELECT COL FROM $D_SCHEMA.TABLE

eval new_var=\""$EXEC_SQL"\"
echo "$new_var"
# output: SELECT COL FROM DEV.TABLE
```